# how to find max of a columns with same name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-manipulation

im having some trouble with this data frame where columns having the same name have to be reduced to values with at least one "1" as "1".

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | a | a | b | c | c | c | d | d |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

to something like this using "or" condition for every column for a huge dataset could be a time-consuming task so I am having trouble figuring it out. I used max(axis=1, level=0) still couldn't make it.

my desired output :

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `max`

```
df = df.max(level=0, axis=1)
```

Comment: hey appreciate the response , as i mentioned above I have already tried that but I get an error as "None of [Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,    ..........],  dtype='int64', length=30507)] are in the [columns]" and I had a hard time figuring that out . mostly because I have a large data .

Comment: @PraneethBhandary Your column is not column yet, can do df.head().to_dict() ?

Comment: i get a alert message saying that some of my columns are ommited  when I try df.head().to_dict()

Comment: hey i figured it out , my data was encoded to 1 and 0 because of that it was in object type   I used  .astype('int').max(level=0, axis=1) and it gave me the output . i appreciate your help